# LinFu - can't quite see how to do what I want

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance, mixins, linfu

Just found LinFu - looks very impressive, but I can't *quite* see how to do what I want to do  - which is multiple inheritance by mixin (composition/delegation as I'd say in my VB5/6 days - when I had a tool to generate the tedious repetitive delegation code - it was whilst looking for a C# equivalent that I found LinFu).

FURTHER EDIT: TO clarify what I mean by composition/delegation and mixin.

```
public class Person : NEOtherBase, IName, IAge 
{

    public Person()
    {

    }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    //Name "Mixin" - you'd need this code in any object that wanted to
    //use the NameObject to implement IName
    private NameObject _nameObj = new NameObject();

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _nameObj.Name; }
        set { _nameObj.Name = value; }
    }
    //--------------------

    //Age "Mixin" you'd need this code in any object that wanted to
    //use the AgeObject to implement IAge
    private AgeObject _ageObj = new AgeObject();

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _ageObj.Age; }
        set { _ageObj.Age = value; }
    }
    //------------------

}

public interface IName
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NameObject : IName
{
    public NameObject()
    {}

    public NameObject(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }

}

public interface IAge 
{
    int Age { get; set; }
}

public class AgeObject : IAge
{
    public AgeObject()
    {}

    public AgeObject(int age)
    {
        _age = age;
    }

    private int _age;
    public int Age { get { return _age; } set { _age = value; } }

}
```

Imagine objects with many more properties, used in many more "subclasses" and you start to see the tedium. A code-gernation tool would actually be just *fine*...

So, LinFu....
The mixin example below is fine but I'd want to have an actual Person *class* (as above) - what's the LinFu-esque way of doing that? Or have I missed the whole point?

EDIT: I need to be able to do this with classes that are already subclassed.

```
DynamicObject dynamic = new DynamicObject();

IPerson person = null;

// This will return false
bool isPerson = dynamic.LooksLike<IPerson>();

// Implement IPerson
dynamic.MixWith(new HasAge(18));
dynamic.MixWith(new Nameable("Me"));

// Now that it’s implemented, this
// will be true
isPerson = dynamic.LooksLike<IPerson>();

if (isPerson)
    person = dynamic.CreateDuck<IPerson>();

// This will return “Me”
string name = person.Name;

// This will return ‘18’
int age = person.Age;
```

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried with a class inheriting from MarshalByRefObject?

Comment: see my edit for why this is not really the answer I'd be looking for.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided some psuedocode of what you'd like to be able to do, and maybe a little context for what you're using this for so people can evaluate whether LinFu is the right approach.

Comment: sorry, I appreciate that "mixin" is a somewhat ambiguous term. I'll revise the question.